# Minecraft rcon tool for Linux Console

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I am searching for a Linux commandline tool to use the rcon to send Command to the minecraft server.

While I found one in the [Minecraft Forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/809788-rcon-client-needed/page__view__findpost__p__10929090) it does not work as expected, most time the Auth Succeeds but the Command does not get executed and the programm quit in reading the results from the Server

Any hints for a working program, or how to fix the mentioned one?

Comment: You want to send commands from the same machine, or a different one?

Comment: The same one, I have already used  HTTPConsole, but since RCon is build in now, would like to use rcon.

Answer (score 6):

Try [mcrcon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrcon/).

Description from the website:

> **Description**
>
> Mcrcon is powerful minecraft rcon client / terminal with bukkit coloring support. It is well suited for remote administration and to be used as part of automated server maintenance scripts. Does not trigger "IO: Broken pipe" or "IO: Connection reset" spam bug on server side.
>
> Precompiled binaries available for Windows (x86), Linux (x86) and Mac OS X (x86 / x86-64).
>
> **Features**
>
> - Interactive terminal mode. Support for Bukkit coloring on Windows and sh compatible shells.
> - Send multiple commands in one command line.
> - Silent mode. Does not print rcon output.
> - Does not cause "IO: Connection reset" spam on server side.
> - Designed to be used as part of the toolchain in server maintenance scipts.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming. While this program may answer the question, you should explain why you think this program is the one the asker needs, and maybe give a little guide on using it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're running minecraft in a [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session, since it's the most convenient way to not force you to keep an ssh connection always open.

You can send a command to screen that it forwards to the application running inside it. For example, I am running it in a screen session called minecraft, and every few hours a script runs, forces a save, toggles autosave off, does a backup of my worlds files, then turns autosave back on.

This is how you start a new screen session called minecraft:

```
screen -S minecraft
```

then you get a shell, you may also pass the command you want to run automatically instead of getting a shell.

Then you can send commands to that session:

```
screen -p 0 -S minecraft -X eval "stuff save-all\015"
```

- `-p 0` sends the message to window 0 in the session
- `-S minecraft` is the session name
- the rest tells to print "save-all" and a newline to the application's stdin

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. While this works most of the time, I had problems with this way especially if I am already connected to the screen session. Therefore I would prefer a solution for rcon since there is a second commandchannel which does not rely or interfere with the STDIN..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is an old post, but I recommend these tools (written in Java):

- [JavaRcon](https://github.com/Pequla/JavaRcon) - terminal application (i wrote it for myself)
- [AdminTools](https://github.com/LukeOnuke/AdminTools) - GUI application

They both work great, recommended